# How to extract number from string

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, powershell-3.0

my array contains string like this :

```
eth1
eth12
eth20
eth35
eth5
```

I want another array who contains only the number of these string :

```
1
12
20
35
5
```

I tried with Trimend() function, but i don't know how to specify this...

thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe you could use a `Replace("eth", "")` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a way

```
$mynewarray = $myarray  -replace 'eth'
```

if text is not always 'eth'

```
$mynewarray = $myarray -replace '\D'
```